# Laravel, Configuración de Apache y NGINX

Tags: laravel, apache, nginx, apache2, deployment

Tengo configurado un entorno de pruebas con **debian, nginx y apache.**

He probado a crear un subdominio con archivos estáticos y dinámicos y cada servidor web me devuelve los archivos correctamente.

Ahora estoy probando de hacer un deploy de un proyecto laravel.
He instalado composer , node todo lo necesario.

Y los vhosts de nginx y apache los tengo de esta manera, el problema lo tengo que la intentar acceder al subdominio me da la página default de "debian apache page"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nginx default**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index.php index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 83.100.XXX.XXX;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


}
```

**Nginx subdominio**

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /var/www/html/cars_backend/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name cars.midominio.es;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
        location ~* ^.*\.php$ {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }
        location ~ /\.(ht|git) {
                deny all;
        }

}
```

**Apache default**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**Apache subdominio**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

        ServerName cars.midominio.es
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cars_backend

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: ¿con qué fin utilizar apache y nginx al tiempo en el mismo servidor?

Comment: Apache para el contenido dinámico, nginx para el estático.

Comment: Solo por curiosidad, ¿qué ventaja trae utilizar apache y nginx de esa manera?

Comment: En la configuración de apahce recuerda apuntar el DocumentRoot a la carpeta public del proyecto.